# How can I call the native console.log method in a Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Jest overrides the native console.log method to collect the logging output for each test. However that can make working with the debugger quite difficult, since nothing will be printed.

[image]

Is there a way to call the native console.log method inside a Jest test?

Comment: I don't think jest is doing this. Could it be something else? What about other console methods like `info` and `error`?

Comment: @HermanStarikov Seems plausible to me since Jest needs to intercept console output to show it after the tests have run. https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-util/src/Console.js

Comment: Oh, I see, makes sense. Why do you want to `console.log` in the debugger instead of just evaluating expressions? Are these kind of alternative debugging methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing a custom TestEnvironment and and custom Reporter (tested with jest@24.7.1):

```
// debugTestEnv.js

const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node')
const console = require('console')

const vanillaConsole = new console.Console({ stdout: process.stdout, stderr: process.stderr })

class DebugTestEnv extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    this.prevConsole = this.global.console
    this.global.console = vanillaConsole
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.global.console = this.prevConsole
    await super.teardown()
  }
}

module.exports = DebugTestEnv
```

```
// debugReporter.js

// In Jest, the DefaultEnvironment constructor changes `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`
// That's why we pass a custom reporter to Jest (we use Jest's BaseReporter for this purpose)
module.exports = require('@jest/reporters/build/base_reporter').default
```

then to run a particular test:

```
jest --runInBand --no-cache --watchAll=false -t="testNameToDebug" --env="./path/to/debugTestEnv.js" --reporters="./path/to/debugReporter.js"
```

This works as well with create-react-app, just replace `jest` with `react-scripts test`.